# SwiftUI MacOS ListView active selection

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am using a `List` inside my MacOS SwiftUI app. I am facing an issue when selecting my first item with the background color of the active cell.

At the beginning I have no selected item. When I press any item in my List, it gets highlighted with the correct user's highlight color. However, there after it is getting displayed in grey.

When I select my other cells thereafter it is working properly and everything stays in the highlighted color.

I created a gif to show the problem:

[image]

When I first click "David John", it is blue and then rapidly grey. I want it to stay in blue.

My main view holds the current state of the active person:

Main View:

```
    @State var selectedPerson: Person?

    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationView
        {
            PersonList(selectedPerson: $selectedPerson)
```

PersonList:

```
 List(selection: $selectedPerson)
 {
     ForEach(personItems.filter {self.checkSearchString(person: $0)}, id: \.self) { person in
```

At beginning, `selectedPerson` is `nil`, as there is no selected person. This is intended.. I tried setting it to the first person in my array, but than the cell is in grey aswell.

Comment: I could not reproduce on replica using your code blocks... would you provide some ready-to-test snapshot?

Comment: @Asperi Thank you for trying to reproduce. I jusst set up a new project to recreate that snapshot only. Not it is working fine too. I try to get a better demo with the issue

Comment: I experienced that grey highlight when setting the State manually. I have to check if I still set it manually somewhere or my State gets overwritten. That would explain why it turn grey. But why only at the first time

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @JanApotheker Yes, I had a Observable Object connected to that view. That was changing when I select a item. Thats why the view was reloading and it appears not active.